# Cannot get webpack.DefinePlugin variable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic3

For some reason I got this error in my terminal after running npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save --save-exact

There was an error in config file 
    "C:\Projects\myproject\config\webpack.config.js". Using defaults instead.
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object. (C:\Projects\myproject\config\webpack.config.js:5:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.fillConfigDefaults (C:\Projects\myproject\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\config.js:316:26)

Is there compatibilty issue in webpack.DefinePlugin and @ionic/app-scripts@latest

here is my webpack.config.js

```
const webpackConfig = require("../node_modules/@ionic/app-
scripts/config/webpack.config");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ENV = process.env.IONIC_ENV; 
const envConfigFile = require(`./config-${ENV}.json`);
webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
           webpackGlobalVars: {
             apiUrl: JSON.stringify(envConfigFile.apiUrl)
           }
     })
 );

here is my service

 import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

 declare const webpackGlobalVars: any;

 @Injectable()
 export class ConfigurationService {
    public static apiUrl = webpackGlobalVars.apiUrl;

 }
```

This is my error in my console.

configuration.service.ts:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackGlobalVars is not defined
    at Object.81 (configuration.service.ts:7)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 09563358e6ae30fad5cb:54)
    at Object.225 (data.service.ts:25)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 09563358e6ae30fad5cb:54)
    at Object.205 (main.js:1228)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 09563358e6ae30fad5cb:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 09563358e6ae30fad5cb:25)
    at main.js:1
81 @ configuration.service.ts:7
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap 09563358e6ae30fad5cb:54
225 @ data.service.ts:25
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap 09563358e6ae30fad5cb:54
205 @ main.js:1228
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap 09563358e6ae30fad5cb:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 09563358e6ae30fad5cb:25
(anonymous) @ main.js:1

Answer (score 0):

read this [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2017-09-28)

> **Breaking Changes** 
>   The webpack config format changed from being a config that is exported to being a dictionary of configs. 
>  Basically, ***the default config now exports a dev and prod property with a config assigned to each***. See an example of the change [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js#L143-L146). This change is setting the stage for adding multiple "environment" support for the next app-scripts release.

so now requiring webpackConfig exports an object that look like this 
 `{ dev: devConfig, prod: prodConfig }`

the changes in the code you posted :

```
const webpackConfig = require("../node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config");
...
webpackConfig.plugins.push( ... ); // --> webpackConfig[ENV].plugins.push( ... );
```